# What is the name of this blurred gradient background light/ray?

Tags: gradient, background, terminology, lighting-effects

I've seen them on websites such as [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs) and [Braydon Coyer](https://braydoncoyer.dev).

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the correct name for these background lights/rays?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There is no "correct" name. Not everything has a specific term in graphic design. You can just use descriptive language such as light rays, sunbeams, light beam gradients,, etc, etc. In meteorology they're referred to as crepuscular rays, but call them what you want. Graphic designers aren't meteorologists.

Comment: Anyway, why do you need the name for this?  Are you trying to look up tutorials? You can ask how to achieve something like this here on GDSE.

Comment: "blurred gradient background light/ray" seems like an apt name to me